# Minikube: can multiple ingress controllers be used per node?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, minikube, nginx-ingress

I know Minikube has an ingress add on which defaults on nginx. Can you create multiple ingress controller in a node? I tried this before and ran into some issue with the ingress add on.

Comment: Why would you like to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure multiple ingress controllers in a node using the [ingress classes](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/multiple-ingress/#using-ingressclasses) each handling a different set of configuration resources.  Each ingress controller can be configured to use different ingress controllers or controllers provided by other vendors by ingress addons and these are the [additional controllers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/#additional-controllers).  Refer to this doc for information on [running multiple ingress controllers](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/running-multiple-ingress-controllers/) and an example of  [How to run multiple ingress controller](https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=000020160) .